# Only pass when not undefined AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my code I am passing an Array of JSON objects from my service to my controller and then to my directive to then be visualised.

Code in Controller:

```
(function(){

'use strict';

angular.module('dashboardApp').controller('DownloadCtrl', DownloadCtrl);

DownloadCtrl.$inject= ['DownloadService','$scope'];

function DownloadCtrl(DownloadService, $scope){
    var self=this;      

    DownloadService.getRoutes()
      .then(function(responseData){       
        self.routes = responseData.data;   

  });

}

})();
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="DownloadCtrl">    

    <donut-chart data='download.routes'></donut-chart>

</div>
```

Directive Code:

```
angular.module('dashboardApp').directive('donutChart',function(){

    function link(scope,element,attr){
        var dataSet = scope.data;

        if(dataSet!==undefined){
            var chart = c3.generate({
                data: dataSet,
                type:'donut'
            });
        }
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link : link,
        scope: {
            data: '='       

        }
    };
});
```

If I **scope.$watch** $scope.data I notice that it appears once and there is no data assigned and then it appears again with data assigned to it. If I don't have the **dataSet!==undefiend** then the code will fail.

It works with the current setup but I feel that there is a better way than simply checking if **dataSet!==undefined**. I think I might of done things in the incorrect order or in the incorrect way.

I would want a way that would allow me to remove the **dataSet!==undefiend**

Comment: I usually use  validation function that returns the function prematurely if fails `if(typeof scope.data === 'undefined'){return;}` it returns without anything and thusly exists the function early. This prevents unnessary indentation from all your main code that should run. Not sure if that's the solution you want though. The only other way I can think of to always rutnr a scope.data value from your datasource.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I might have to do something like that. It's just in all the books or tutorials I read there isn't any checking so I assume there is something else going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `return` from the link function if `scope.data` is `null`

```
function link(scope,element,attr){
    if(scope.data == null){
     return;
    }

    var dataSet = scope.data;

    var chart = c3.generate({
        data: dataSet,
        type:'donut'
    });

};
```

Comment: I think that returning in a link function is not a good way because stops you from adding more business logic if needed...

Comment: @Hitmands Wrong. If the business logic expects/operates on not null value, Its nothing wrong returning from the function.

Comment: it is a scalability question... if you need to do it in future?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use return in your link function because prevents the ability to add more business logic, is not scalable in my opinion...

Just check if `scope.data` isn't a *falsy* value and then do what you need.
Falsy values are: `false`, `0`, `null`, `undefined`, `''`

if you perform a check on one of these falsy values the `if` statement isn't satisfied.

```js
{
  link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    if(scope.data) {
      d3.generate({
        data: scope.data
      });
    }
  }
}
```